# MA model or ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

Anyone can give some suggestions to decide which model should i use for this time series forecast?
It seems it is [MA(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model#:%7E:text=The%20moving%2Daverage%20model%20specifies,stochastic%20(imperfectly%20predictable)%20term.) by checking two plots? OR i can also try ARIMA model to compare each other?
The ACF  shows a sharp drop at lag 1 and damped wave pattern while PACF should show a geometric trend. From this, we might say MA(q) model might fit the series.

[image]

Comment: I suggest to see if the series are stationary first and then use `armasubsets` function from `library(TSA)`, this will give you a subset of ARMA models where it is possible to choose the best model based on BIC criteria

Comment: Or use a more refined approach in the form of `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package.

Comment: It seems to me you are referring to lag 0 as the first lag of the ACF plot. From what I see there is no signifacnt autocorrelation in the first lag. Lag 0 is the autocorrelation with itself it should be avoided.